# Order in xml files

Tags: xml

I have a file with

```
<first><second><third><fourth /></third></second></first>
```

but I want to convert to:

```
<first>
     <second>
          <third>
               <fourth />
          </third>
     </second> 
</first>
```

is there any converter? Mac os x?

Comment: Almost any xml editor. Open the xml file, format it (`Format all document` menu item or the like), save.

Answer (score 0):

I found package to my editor - atom.io - called atom-beautify.

Thanks.